# ChromeOS - Linux apps blurred fonts

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os, font-smoothing

I have 4k monitor connected and on ChromeOS itself fonts look excellent and sharp:
[image]
[image]

But all apps running on Linux vm has ugly, blurred fonts:

[image]

Is there any way make fonts for Linux apps rendered the same as on main ChromeOS system?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your VM is not set to the native resolution.

In virtual machines you have to assure the capabilities of your physical display are passed into the VM so the auto-detection of the Linux can do the rest.

If that is not the problem, might be the High-DPI compensation features are active:

You should look at the configuration of the "display settings" within your Linux in the VM. There often are some sort of scaling setting available (availability and appearance depend on your Linux distribution):

- "User interface scale" (set to 100% or "normal")
- Fractional scaling controls

On command-line you can check

```
xrandr --query
```

for more information.

Some sample output of `xrandr --query`:
(the "current" value is of interest.)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   [...]
```

###### UPDATE: Container

As you write, you are not using a VM but CromeOS' **container** feature to run Linux apps the settings within the VM are not relevant for your question.

X-apps and Wayland-apps are served by ChromOS' own nested Wayland compositor called "[Sommelier](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/HEAD/vm_tools/sommelier/README.md)".

To take control you start the Linux-app using Sommelier at the commandline of the ChromeOS Terminal, providing environment and parameters:

```
sommelier -X --scale=0.75 --dpi="120" inkscape
```

`--scale=0.75` will scale the display. A value larger than `1` will tend to blur font and object within the container. This parameter has only influence *within* the window of the container

`SOMMELIER_SCALE=0.75` is the environment variable that represents the same as the parameter `--scale=0.75`. The parameter should override the environment setting.

`GDK_SCALE=2` influences the Gnome desktop. This is the Hi-DPI compensation for all apps in the Gnome Desktop, so also Sommelier/Wayland/X11 as a "onion shell" that wraps the results of Sommelier.

Many Linux apps read the DPI (Dots Per Inch) and compensate their internal sizing to provide a native, smooth and sharp experience for the Hi-DPI problem. Having proper DPI settings for each connected display provides the chance that the app will present its content in almost the same size on all connected displays.

`--dpi=""` or not mentioning it will provide the exact DPI-settings of the display known by ChromeOS to the Linux app run in Sommelier.

`--dpi=120` will override the DPI value provided by ChromeOS.

`--dpi=75,96,120,160,200,240` will provide a "bucket" of valid DPI-values to Sommelier. A real DPI value of `172` will be passed as `160` to the Linux app. This is sometimes necessary as some Linux apps only accept some discrete values as valid DPI settings. These you have to find out and write in the "bucket", when you experience unexpected sizing within distinct Linux apps.

---

To "remove" the blurring in your Linux app, you should first start with `--scale=1`. And only use this single scaling factor.

As the not setting `GDK_SCALE` the global setting of this variable will be active, the blur provided by this parameter should be the same at all ChromeOS apps and Sommelier apps.

If the blurring disappeared you should judge the sizing of the objects within the Linux app compared to the sizing of the other ChromeOS apps.

1. If in all apps the objects are to small/large, then the `GDK_Scale` is the right parameter to tune. But as this is a scaling of pixels any value larger than *native* `GDK_Scale=1.0` will result in more or less visible blurring. Helpful are straight factors like `1.5` or `2`.
   Note that just changing `GDK_Scale` in a terminal will not have influence to the other CromeOS apps. This you have to change at the global settings.
2. If only the Linux app's sizing is uncomfortable, then you have to weight the (dis-)advantages of `--scale=...` and `--dpi=...`.

   - `--scale=<value>` (or `SOMMELIER_SCALE=<value>`) larger than *native* `1.0` will start blurring. Here also straight factors like  `1.5` or `2` help to make the blurring less visible.
   - `--dpi=<value>` will fix the used DPI of the app and changing the display at a multi monitor setup might produce unwanted jumps in the displayed sizing. But it offers the chance to prohibit blurring and get the desired sizing.

---

Please provide some feedback of your test results and decisions.

Comment: You don't know how it works on ChromeOS + integrated Linux app support, vm has no its own X server , so your answer is not helpful: https://chromeos.dev/en/linux - that's linux container only, similar to Docker

Comment: No, specifically ChromeOS not. But reading your link that's not a VM anymore, just an emulation. So the path how to manage it, obviously is different. But the point that the Linux app has no hint at what resolution it is running, is given. Changing this to fit the display hardware will solve your problem.

Comment: I guess I need to force scale/dpi, because ChromeOS is not able to do that correctly. But still, I'm not sure how to do that. It looks like Linux app thinks resolution is very low and ChromeOS just makes dumb upscaling and result is poor

Comment: Obviously ChromeOS' Wayland integration "Sommelier" looks to be responsible: [ChromiumOS: Sommelier # Densitiy & Scaling, Content Scaling, Scalefactor, DPI](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/HEAD/vm_tools/sommelier/README.md#density-and-scaling)

Comment: The setting for "Sommelier" at program start should probably be `--scale=1.0`. Same functionality goes to the variable `SOMMELIER_SCALE=1.0`. But i doubt all your Linux Container apps use Sommelier. So this might be only a partitial solution.

Comment: That may be good clues. But there's no info how to override default args like scaling

Comment: On the one hand you can start the container manually by commandline in the terminal. There you can extend the options by the scaling parameters: `sommelier -X --scale=1.0 --dpi="" inkscape`  should start the app "inkscape" (Passing `--dpi="" ` sends the real dpi of the system. Later on in a second step you might want to optimize this value, too.). // On the other hand it should be posssible to set the variable `SOMMELIER_SCALE=1.0` globally, so all sommelier-apps should respect it. But thats usefull at the point when we know this option does the clue.

Comment: Command: `GDK_SCALE=3 sommelier -X --scale=3 --dpi=200` gives pretty goof results. However, that's actually still big mess. Some apps ignores 'dpi` param (but result is still good, for example Android Studio), some others works fine, but cursor size is too small, some others like LibreOfice are not able to dsplay anything, gui is broken with parts not visible

Comment: I think, any scaling should disabled and all values should be as the physical settings are. (1) to use the DPI of ChromeOS set `--dpi=""` (2) prevent scaling in the container use `--scale=1` (3) To do no scale-manipulation by the desktop manager use `GDK_SCALE=1`.  // ***Only without scaling the fonts and objects are rendered in native resolution and won't be blured.*** Also tuning several options at one time will prohibit that you understand the effects of each single option. The result is that you're talking about *"pretty good results"* but not about *"that's the solution"*.

Comment: Please: Tune one after the other, not all at once. Find out, which are the default values of these settings and post them here. Then tell about the option `--scale=1`. Do not add not-tuned parameters so they will have their default values set by ChromeOS.

Comment: @user1209216 : Please test and tell the output of the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor`

Comment: Sadly, my hardware does not work anymore, so for now, issue is paused... once I bring it to live again, I will return here to solve problem.